# Wi-Fi Network only appears after I connect to another Wi-Fi network

Tags: macbook-pro, network, wifi, tethering

This is a very intriguing problem. Every time I'll connect my MacBook Air mid 2013 with OS X Yosemite 10.10.3 to my wi-fi network at home, I can't, cause it won't be available in the list of networks available. 
What I do? I turn no my Android tethering hotspot, and only after I connect to this network, my home wi-fi will be shown.

What might it be???

Answer (score 1):

The first part is for testing.

You need to use the terminal and manually connect to it.

Turn On

```
networksetup -setairportpower en0 on
```

Find (you can skip this if you already know the Name)

```
/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/Apple80211.framework/Versions/A/Resources/airport scan
```

Connect

```
networksetup -setairportnetwork en0 WIFI_SSID_I_WANT_TO_JOIN WIFI_PASSWORD
```

Enter/replace your WiFi name and password in the above.

This should have connected you to your Network.

- In your Network settings your home network should be in the top of the list.
- Open your router settings and change the network name to test if problem with naming. While in Router setting, change the channel to #5 (usually the least crowded one) to eliminate interferences.
- Finally, run WiFi diagnostics, by holding the "alt" key and clicking on the WiFi icon, then selecting the WiFi Diagnostics.